# What am I doing wrong with the code for timezone fix?

Tags: command-line, clock

I was wondering what I was doing wrong or omitting for the previously described "Clock time is off on dual boot" issue.

The most popular solution is noted below, but I cannot get the command to run:

To tell your Ubuntu system that the hardware clock is set to 'local' time:

```
1.edit /etc/default/rcS

2.add or change the following section
# Set UTC=yes if your hardware clock is set to UTC (GMT)
UTC=no
```

Now I am basically a Linux noob, so I figure I must be entering the command wrong.  I was able to run:

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
```

and this fixed the clock issue.

Could someone explain why not just use this simpler code, what is the difference with the other solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**: on current systems `sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1` is the correct way.

You have been caught by a change in the way time is configured on Ubuntu. Editing `/etc/default/rcS` was how it worked before *systemd* as init system. (Either *initd* or *upstart* were used then).

In any case when you edit a file beneath `/etc` you set how the system acts after the next boot. To have the setting effective immediately you almost always have to give an additional command (either reload a daemon/service or talk to the kenel or ...)

So from 15.04 onward the setting in `/etc/default/rcS` is probably entirely ignored. See [NTP](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html) in the Ubuntu server Guide, whereas [UbuntuTime](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime) in the communit WiKi is a bit outdated and only mentions `timedatectl` way below.